# Query that counts total records per day and total records with same time timestamp and id per day in Bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have timeseries data like this:

| time | id | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2018-04-25 22:00:00 UTC | A | 1 |
| 2018-04-25 23:00:00 UTC | A | 2 |
| 2018-04-25 23:00:00 UTC | A | 2.1 |
| 2018-04-25 23:00:00 UTC | B | 1 |
| 2018-04-26 23:00:00 UTC | B | 1.3 |

How do i write a query to produce an output table with these columns:

- date: the truncated time
- records: the number of records during this date
- records_conflicting_time_id: the number of records during this date where the combination of `time`, `id` are not unique. In the example data above the two records with id==A at 2018-04-25 23:00:00 UTC would be counted for date 2018-04-25

So the output of our query should be:

| date | records | records_conflicting_time_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2018-04-25 | 4 | 2 |
| 2018-04-26 | 1 | 0 |

Getting `records` is easy, i just truncate the `time` to get date and then group by `date`. But i'm really struggling to produce a column that counts the number of records where `id` + `time` is not unique over that date...

Comment: Can you share your sample data and your expected data? You may also check this SO guideline: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Sure. I added some sample input / output data. I think it's easier to understand than adding my actual raw data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select date(time) date, 
  sum(cnt) records, 
  sum(if(cnt > 1, cnt, 0)) conflicting_records
from (
  select time, id, count(*) cnt
  from your_table
  group by time, id
)
group by date
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
with YOUR_DATA as
  (
              select  cast('2018-04-25 22:00:00 UTC' as timestamp) as `time`, 'A' as id, 1.0 as value
    union all select  cast('2018-04-25 23:00:00 UTC' as timestamp) as `time`, 'A' as id, 2.0 as value
    union all select cast('2018-04-25 23:00:00 UTC' as timestamp) as `time`, 'A' as id, 2.1 as value
    union all select cast('2018-04-25 23:00:00 UTC' as timestamp) as `time`, 'B' as id, 1.0 as value
    union all select cast('2018-04-26 23:00:00 UTC' as timestamp) as `time`, 'B' as id, 1.3 as value
  )
select  cast(timestamp_trunc(t1.`time`, day) as date) as `date`,
        count(*) as records,
        case when count(*)-count(distinct cast(t1.`time` as string) || t1.id) = 0 then 0
          else count(*)-count(distinct cast(t1.`time` as string) || t1.id)+1
        end as records_conflicting_time_id
from    YOUR_DATA t1
group by cast(timestamp_trunc(t1.`time`, day) as date)
;
```